# Delete single snapshot in unmanaged disk with azure python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to delete unmanaged snapshots for unmanaged disks (cteaion time less than X). The only option I can see is to either delete ALL the snapshots and leave the disk or delete the disk and snapshots all together.

The code I'm working with:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timdelta

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, RetentionPolicy


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url="https://{}.blob.core.windows.net".format("myStorageAccount"),
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
)

containers = blob_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)

for container in containers:
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container.name)
    blobs = container_client.list_blobs(include=["snapshots", "metadata"])

    for blob in blobs:
        if blob.name.endswith(".vhd"):
            if blob.snapshot:
                
                 # Do some checks
                 if blob.creation_time < datetime.now(blob.creation_time.tzinfo) - timedelta(days=30)
                     try:
                         blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
                         blob_client.delete_blob()
                         print(f"Deleted - {blob.name} in  {container.name} from {storage_account.name} in subscription {subscription_id} - criteria passed")
                     except Exception as error:
                         print(error)
```

However, I get the error that it's trying to delete the parent disk and it can't delete it because it has snapshots. But, what I am trying to do is just delete the single snapshot if it meets the creation time check.

```sh
This operation is not permitted because the blob has snapshots.
RequestId:<REDACTED>
Time:2021-01-21T11:29:06.9708873Z
ErrorCode:SnapshotsPresent
Error:None
```

The only way I can seem to delete snapshots is to specify to the client to delete all of them relative to the disk

```py
blob_client.delete_blob(delete_snapshots="only")
```

It seems as though even if the blob item I am working with is related to a snapshot the name of the blob is still the original disk. Referecing `blob.snapshot` only presents me with the timestamp of the snapshot.

From the portal I can delete individual snapshots so there must be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems silly but I have to create *another* client for the blob using a separate class, but it seems to work. Of the 3 or so storage account clients I have in the code just to list the blobs you'd think one of them could delete a snapshot?

I updated the try block to use the `BlobClient` and then specify the snapshot ID.

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, RetentionPolicy, BlobClient

try:
    blob_client = BlobClient(account_url=oauth_url, container_name=container.name, blob_name=blob.name, snapshot=blob.snapshot, credential=default_credential)
    blob_client.delete_blob()
    print(f"Deleted - {blob.name} in  {container.name} from {storage_account.name} in subscription {subscription_id} - criteria passed")
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```